# How can I convert a "Time" in an excel column to be formatted as time, without the date?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, datetime, time

I'm trying to convert about 5-6 digit number into a time value "00:00:00" in Excel using pandas, but no matter what I try it won't work or errors are thrown. To note, I only need the time part (both columns cannot be merged for reporting purposes).

```
#I've tried:
autoLog['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(autoLog['TIME'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.hour
autoLog['TIME'] = pd.to_timedelta(autoLog['TIME'], unit='s')
autoLog['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(autoLog['TIME'], format='%H:%M:%S', infer_datetime_format=True)

#I also have a "DATE" column converting numbers into a date format and that works fine:
autoLog['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(autoLog['DATE'], format='%Y%m%d', 
infer_datetime_format=True)
autoLog['DATE'] = autoLog['DATE'].dt.date
```

What it should be:

```
DATE        TIME      FILE NAME
2023-04-11  10:59:27  123493
2023-04-11  10:59:27  456783
2023-04-11  10:59:27  895452
2023-04-11  11:35:27  126446
2023-04-11  11:35:27  464674
```

First "to_datetime" solution doesn't run due to error:

> "time data '22254' does not match format '%H:%M:%S' (match)"

What it is using to_timedelta:

```
DATE        TIME    FILE NAME
2023-04-11  0       123493
2023-04-11  0       456783
2023-04-11  0       895452
2023-04-11  1       126446
2023-04-11  1       464674
```

What it is using to_datetime(third solution):

```
DATE        TIME                      FILE NAME
2023-04-11  1970-01-01 00:00:00       123493
2023-04-11  1970-01-01 00:00:00       456783
2023-04-11  1970-01-01 00:00:00       895452
2023-04-11  1970-01-01 00:00:00       126446
2023-04-11  1970-01-01 00:00:00       464674
```

I've solved the date part, but can't do the time part. Date and time are in two separate columns in excel and it must remain the same for reporting purposes (spreadsheet cannot be altered but content in cells can).

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: *Don't* try to modify the "format" of Python's dates or times - they have none, they're binary values. You'll only mangle the times. In Excel dates and times are stored internally as a float. The way they're displayed depends on the numeric format *of the cell's style*. Pandas offers only limited styling support, through either the `float_format` parameter of `to_excel` or the `date_format` and `datetime_format` parameters of `ExcelWriter`

Comment: Check the documentation of XlsxWriter, the default engine used by Pandas. The page [Working with dates and times](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_dates_and_time.html) explains how dates and times are stored and displayed, and how to control the display format

Comment: So you load your excel spreadsheet to a pandas dataframe, is that correct? and now the time column from the spreadsheet is a 5-6 digit number (integer), is that correct?

Comment: Correct, the len of digits can vary from 5-6 because it is a report with different times. The conversion to data frame isn't messing anything up, though.

Comment: did you try to cast to string, zero-fill to 6 chars, then parse with correct format `%H%M%S`?  something like `pd.to_datetime(autoLog['TIME'].astype(str).str.zfill(6), format='%H%M%S')`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Excel represents date/time as fractional days (float), so if you have a 5-6 digit number in a spreadsheet that represents (h)hmmss, you can't convert that to a time directly by changing the cell style ("format"). You can do the conversion (calculation) in Python / pandas rather easily; but as you write, styling options going from Python to Excel are limited. You'd still have to change the cell style to 'Time' in Excel.

Comment: @FObersteiner your solution plus some extra code worked perfectly, thank you! Also, formatting issues noted!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to FObersteiner plus some extra code, the output now is correct.

Before:

```
DATE        TIME    FILE NAME
2023-04-11  105927  123493
2023-04-11  105927  456783
2023-04-11  105927  895452
2023-04-11  113527  126446
2023-04-11  113527  464674
```

After:

```
DATE        TIME      FILE NAME
2023-04-11  10:59:27  123493
2023-04-11  10:59:27  456783
2023-04-11  10:59:27  895452
2023-04-11  11:35:27  126446
2023-04-11  11:35:27  464674
```

So my solution ended up being:

```
autoLog['TIME'] = autoLog['TIME'].astype(str).str.zfill(6)
autoLog['TIME'] = autoLog['TIME'].str.replace(r"(\d{2}(?!$))", r"\1:")
```